# How to change right-bounded interval into left-bounded interval in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to divide my main interval [0,1) into equal parts. I use Interval from pandas.

My main interval:

```
main_interval = pd.Interval(left=0, right=1, closed='left')
```

And I get the information:

`Interval(0, 1, closed='left')`

so I think I did that ok.

But when I want to divide this interval into equal parts (equal subintervals), my new subintervals are right-bounded, not left-bounded as I want.

My code:

```
result=[]
def my_function_interval(k):
    for i in range(0,k):
        rr = (main_interval+i)/k
        result.append(rr)
    print(result)
```

So when I do `my_function_interval(2)`, I get:

`[Interval(0.0, 0.5, closed='right'), Interval(0.5, 1.0, closed='right')]`

How should I change my code to get left-bounded subintervals? I mean [0,0.5) and [0.5,1]?

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could convert your interval into a left-bounded interval with the following code:

```py
rr = pd.Interval(left=rr.left, right=rr.right, closed='left')
```

([Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html).)